# Get the value of an input field located inside a table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is supposed to be a shopping cart inspired by [jeasyui.com](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd2.php). I have three problems with it.

1. I can't get the value of the quantity when it's changed in the input box.
2. When I remove an item from the cart, that service must be available in its appropriate tab again.
3. The services get indented for each new tab. I need them to start at the beginning everytime.

This is the code I have so far:[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Intelli/full/VPYgGw/). I'm sorry if it's messy, it's my first time working with javascript/jquery. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
function removeProduct(el) {
 var name1 = $(el).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
 var price1;
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (name1 == data[i][0]) {
   price1 = data[i][2];
 }
   var className = $(el).parent().attr('class');
   /**Add a new list item in item class with the class name and the service name and price in paragraphs.*/
   $(el).closest('tr').remove();
 }
}

function changeQuantity(el) {
var name1 = $(el).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
var quantity1 = $(el).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).value;
var price1;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i][1] = quantity1;
  data[i][2] = price * quantity1;
  if (name1 == data[i][0]) {
    price1 = data[i][2];
  }
}
 $(el).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html("<input type='number' value='" + quantity1 + "' style='width:100%;'>");
 $(el).closest('tr').find('td').eq(3).html(price1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the quantity do:

```
$(el).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).find('input').val();
```

Because you are physically removing the element from the DOM with `source.remove();` you can't easily. I would suggest adding a class to the element that will hide it. And then when you remove it from the card, remove that class.

For your third issue, remove the CSS that hides the product classes and instead add this:

Remove:

```
.Biostatistics {
    display: none;
}
.ClinicalLaboratory {
    display:none;
}
.Something{
    display:none;
}
```

Add:

```
.Products li {
    display: none;
}
```

Also change your js to be like this (adding the closest('li'):

```
x[i].closest('li').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! I was wondering though, how to get the class name of the immediate parent class to the element that was dropped. For example, if I drag and drop Biostats Service, I want to get "Biostatistics". If I use "$(source).attr('class')", in the onDrop function, I get "item" instead of "Biostatistics"